# Linux kernel "historical" git repository with full history

Tags: linux, git, linux-kernel, kernel

I think many developers like to investigate sources with the help of `git gui blame`. As explained in the [commit for Linux-2.6.12-rc2](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=1da177e4c3f41524e886b7f1b8a0c1fc7321cac2) (also [mirrored at Github](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/1da177e4c3f41524e886b7f1b8a0c1fc7321cac2)), it needs to have special historical Linux repository for this purpose.

> #### Linux-2.6.12-rc2
>
> Initial git repository build. I’m not bothering with the full history,
>   even though we have it. We can create a separate “historical” git
>   archive of that later if we want to, and in the meantime it’s about
>   3.2GB when imported into git — space that would just make the early
>   git days unnecessarily complicated, when we don’t have a lot of good
>   infrastructure for it.
>
> Let it rip!

I have looked at a lot of the prepared historical repositories but I didn’t find one containing changes going back to version zero, so I gave up and am asking this question here.

Answer (score 58):

Here is my setup.

I have a repository with a clone of the following remotes:

- https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git
- https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git
- https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/tglx/history.git
- https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/davej/history.git

And the following grafts (`info/grafts`):

```
1da177e4c3f41524e886b7f1b8a0c1fc7321cac2 e7e173af42dbf37b1d946f9ee00219cb3b2bea6a
7a2deb32924142696b8174cdf9b38cd72a11fc96 379a6be1eedb84ae0d476afbc4b4070383681178
```

With these grafts, I have an unbroken view of the kernel history since 0.01. The first graft glues together the very first release in Linus' repository with the corresponding release of `tglx/history.git`. The second graft glues together `tglx/history.git` and `davej/history.git`.

There are a few older versions missing, and the older versions have release granularity instead of patch granularity, but this is the best setup I know of.

---

**Edit:** Dave Jones pointed me to http://www.archive.org/details/git-history-of-linux, which seems to be exactly what you want.

Comment: Note that, since the kernel.org compromise a few months ago, all repositories were removed from git.kernel.org. `torvalds/linux.git`, `stable/linux-stable.git`, and `tglx/history.git` are already back; `davej/history.git` is still missing.

Comment: I uploaded my copy of the `davej/history.git` repository to http://repo.or.cz/w/davej-history.git

Comment: thanks for the mirror! I made additional mirrors on github https://github.com/schwabe/davej-history and https://github.com/schwabe/tglx-history just in case

Comment: For those coming to this solution post-2024, `.git/info/grafts` has been deprecated and replaced with `git replace`. To install the provided grafts, do `git replace --graft 1da177e4c3f41524e886b7f1b8a0c1fc7321cac2 e7e173af42dbf37b1d946f9ee00219cb3b2bea6a; git replace --graft 7a2deb32924142696b8174cdf9b38cd72a11fc96 379a6be1eedb84ae0d476afbc4b4070383681178`. You can also use `git replace --convert-graft-file` to convert from the old graft file setup.

Answer (score 20):

Here is a review of available 2018 options with a focus on tag availability and date correctness.

### https://archive.org/download/git-history-of-linux/full-history-linux.git.tar

Developed by Dave Jones, and made available on `archive.org`.

- Covers early versions to 2010.
- 244,464 commits
- Just 184 tags, covering versions in 2.6. The tags [that should have been created for all versions](https://github.com/kernelslacker/linux-historic-scripts/blob/master/import.sh#L45) seem to be missing.
- Early commits have realistic dates, but incorrect times (`11:00:00 199X -0600`).
- Some dates seem to be incorrect. For example, both `2.1.110` and `2.1.111` are dated `Wed May 20 11:00:00 1998 -0600`, although the latest file in the `2.1.111` snapshot is dated `1998-07-25 09:17`.
- The creation process is [documented on GitHub](https://github.com/kernelslacker/linux-historic-scripts) and seems very thorough.

### https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/tglx/history.git/

Created by Thomas Gleixner.

- Covers 2.4.0 to 2.6.12-rc2.
- Contains 170 tags covering 2.5.X and 2.6.X.
- 63,428 commits
- Dates are correct.
- Contains patches converted into commits.

### https://github.com/mpe/linux-fullhistory

Created by Michael Ellerman, derived from work by Yoann Padioleau, based on historical trees reconstructed by Dave Jones and Thomas Gleixner, and Linus' mainline tree.

- Covers full history
- Provides only 558 tags, mostly starting at 2.0.0.
- 790,471 commits
- Same issues with dates as in Dave Jones's repo.
- Uses replace objects instead of grafts.

### https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/history/history.git/

Owned by the Linux *history team*.

- Covers early versions to 2.6.33-rc5.
- 1710 tags, starting with 0.10, covering most early versions.
- 244,774 commits
- Most historic versions are incorrectly dated `Fri Nov 23 15:09:04 2007 -0500`.

### https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/

Modern Linux development.

- Covers 2.6.12-rc2 (2005) until today
- 569 tags
- 777,419 commits (August 2018)
- Proper commits

Answer (score 12):

the referenced repos no longer exist.  the new one is here:
https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/history/history.git/

if you're like me and want to keep some repos sep, you can leverage alternates with the graft to do so:

```
# Same dir as main linux
$ git clone --bare git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/history/history.git
$ cd linux/.git/
$ echo ../../../history.git/objects >> objects/info/alternates
$ echo 1da177e4c3f41524e886b7f1b8a0c1fc7321cac2 e7e173af42dbf37b1d946f9ee00219cb3b2bea6a >> info/grafts
$ echo 7a2deb32924142696b8174cdf9b38cd72a11fc96 379a6be1eedb84ae0d476afbc4b4070383681178 >> info/grafts
```

Answer (score 5):

The best what I've found is [git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/davej/history.git](http://git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/davej/history.git). History tracking there starts from Linux-0.01 but many comments are poor something like "Import 2.1.38pre1".

Anyway there is a lot of knowledge.

Thanks for help!