# Git: Show all of the various changes to a single line in a specified file over the entire git history

Tags: git

I've looked around, and am not sure if this is possible, but here goes:

I have a (javascript) file (say /lib/client.js) in which I have a unique identifier assigned to a variable, like so:
   `var identifier = "SOME_IDENTIFIER";`

You can think of the identifier like a version number:  Periodically, we'll change this variable to a new identifier.

What I'd like to do is find all of the unique identifiers we've ever used.  How can I do this with git?

I imagine there might be a way to search through the git history, and print the line matching `"var identifier ="`.  I could de-dupe this list manually.

Anyway, I'd appreciate any insight here.  Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieve the commit log for a specific line in a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435343/retrieve-the-commit-log-for-a-specific-line-in-a-file)

Answer (score 165):

Since Git 1.8.4, there is a more direct way to answer your question.

Assuming that line `110` is the line saying `var identifier = "SOME_IDENTIFIER";`, then do this:

```
git log -L110,110:/lib/client.js
```

This will return every commit which touched that line of code.

See [`git-log`'s documentation for the `-L` command line parameter](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt--Lltstartgtltendgtltfilegt).

Answer (score 61):

See the man page for `git-log` and `gitdiffcore`.  I believe this command would do it, but it might not be quite right:

```
git log -G "var identifier =" file.js
```

---

**EDIT:** Here's a rough start for a bash script to show the actual lines.  This might be more what you're looking for.

```
for c in $(git log -G "something" --format=%H -- file.js); do
    git --no-pager grep -e "something" $c -- file.js
done
```

It uses `git log -G` to find the interesting commits, using `--format=%H` to produce a list of commit hashes.  It then iterates over each interesting commit, asking `git grep` to show the lines from that commit and file that contain the regex, prefaced with the commit hash.

---

**EDIT:** Changed to use `-G` instead of `-S` as suggested in comments.

Comment: @Rob - thanks for this - small edit to your script though - putting just the filename only shows commits that just affect that file - if a commit referenced other files it is not listed

Comment: @AdrianCornish - Glad it was helpful.  I think the OP wanted to just look at one file, but you are quite correct that removing the filename is probably a more generally useful script.

Comment: I have a more difficult situation. The file in question moved from paht_a/file to path_b/file. Now when I do it in path_b it only show changes up to when the file moves from path_a to path_b. If I do it in path_a it tells me 

    fatal: ambiguous argument 'file': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.

Comment: @AndySong - If the string you are searching for is unique enough, perhaps you can just leave off the file name and still get what you're looking for.

Comment: Was more convenient for me - place a blank line after each commit, enumerate lines: `sfile=path/to/some_file; sfind='string_to_find'; for c in $(git log -G $sfind --format=%H -- $sfile); do git --no-pager grep -e $sfind -n $c -- $sfile; echo; done`

Answer (score 14):

You can also do this with gitk:

```
gitk file.js
```

In the "commit" drop down, choose "adding/removing string:" and in the text box next to it, enter "var identifier =", and any commits that add or remove lines that contain that string will be highlighted.

Comment: This helped pinpoint the commit at which the line containing "var identifier =" was added, but it is not showing subsequent commits that modified this line.

Comment: Have you tried `git blame file.js` or `git gui blame file.js`?

Comment: I know what git blame does; I am looking for a full history of revisions, not a single diff.

Comment: `git gui blame file.js` will do that...it'll show you all revisions of a file and who changed it; you can just click backwards through the history.

Comment: I ended up stepping through visually with gitk.  I imagine there is some elegant git technique to do this, but gitk was good enough.  Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

If you adapt @rob's answer just a bit, `git log` will basically do this for you, if all you need is a visual comparison:

```bash
git log -U0 -S "var identifier =" path/to/file
```

`-U0` means output in patch mode (`-p`), and show zero lines of context around the patch.

You can even do this across branches:

```bash
git log -U0 -S "var identifier =" branchname1 branchname2 -- path/to/file
```

There may be a way to suppress the diff header, but I don't know of one.

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

In [magit](http://magit.vc/), you can do this with

```
l, =L
```

It will then ask you for file and start,end lines.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to list all the pet names that the Linux kernel has been given. This is set in the `Makefile` in the [kernel Git repo](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git) (although this isn't the [full history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264283/linux-kernel-historical-git-repository-with-full-history)). I didn't want to rely on it being a specific line number and I wanted the line's actual content rather than the commit refs, and I wanted to remove duplicates without affecting the order. I came up with this:

```
git log --format=format:%H Makefile | xargs -I{} git show {}:Makefile | awk -F '=' '/^NAME = /{print $NF}' | awk '!x[$0]++'
```

It first uses `git log` to get the commits affecting that file then passes the file content, obtained with `git show`, at that ref through awk which extracts the line of interest and a 2nd [awk de-duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11532197) the list.

Just in case it's useful to anyone.