# How to delete redundant environment variables in MacOS?

Tags: bash, rvm, environment-variables

I have my path

```
~/desktop/Ruby » echo $PATH
```

and the result

> /Users/zhang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/Users/zhang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/bin:/Users/zhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/zhang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/Users/zhang/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/bin:/Users/zhang/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/bin:/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/Users/zhang/.rvm/bin:/Users/zhang/.rvm/bin:/Users/zhang/.rvm/bin

Here i have lots of redundancies in the path, perhaps I've something like “PATH=$PATH:.....” in my bash, but i didn't find it..

So 
   1. How can i delete redundant environment variables in macOS? 
   2. how can i make sure environement viriable without the repeats when i add the path? 
   3. how can i make the redundant path appear just one time?

Comment: @Max I'm intrigued - under what circumstances could it be good to repeat?

Comment: You may not be aware of `/etc/paths` which also sets your PATH.

Comment: well, i care about i because i'm a virgo..haha. i'm also in confuse in which condition could it be good to repeat. @Max

Answer (score 0):

#### How can I eliminate existing duplicates?

With some standard Unix tools (most of which I hope are readily available on OS X), you can eliminate duplicates like this. Note that some of these tools may work slightly differently on `OS X`, but these commands should work with minor tweaks. I have only tested on Linux because I do not have access to `OS X` at the moment.

```
PATH=`echo $PATH | sed 's/:/\n/g' | sort | uniq | paste -s --delimiters=":"`
```

This has the unfortunate side effect of sorting your `PATH` which may be undesirable if you have multiple versions of the same binary in different parts of your `PATH`.

In order to avoid this side effect, we can borrow a trick from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11532197/391161) to do `uniq` without sort.

```
PATH=`echo $PATH | sed 's/:/\n/g' | awk ' !x[$0]++' | paste -s --delimiters=":"`
```

---

#### How can I avoid adding redundant paths to the `PATH` variable?

Use one of the [many answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/229606/391161) for [String contains in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/229551/391161) to check whether `PATH` already includes the path you are about to add.

```
if [[ $PATH != *newpath* ]]
then
   export PATH=$PATH:newpath
fi
```

Comment: ~ » source ~/.bashrc                                               zhang@zt-mac
paste: illegal option -- -
usage: paste [-s] [-d delimiters] file ...
/Users/zhang/.rvm/scripts/rvm:12: command not found: uname
/Users/zhang/.rvm/scripts/rvm:14: command not found: ps
git_prompt_info:1: command not found: git  @merlin2011 that is the result when i launch your solution.

Answer (score 0):

The last line from my own `$HOME/.profile` file:

```
eval $(perl -e 'printf qq{export %s="%s";}, $_, join(":", grep { -d $_ && !$seen{ $_ }++ } split /:/, $ENV{$_}), $_ for( qw(PATH MANPATH) );')
```

It:

- cleans up the environment variables PATH and MANPATH as

  - removes duplicates
  - removes nonexistent directories
- creates the new `export PATH="... cleaned up path ..."`
- reinitialise the new PATH a MANPATH

for the test: replace the `eval` with `echo` to show, what is doing exactly