# Analyzing one column from a larger file

Tags: python, pandas

I am using Pandas. I am trying to read in one column of names from a larger file. This file in total is 35GBs which made my kernel die. So I would like to just read in one of the columns. Then I would then like "chunk" this data, so the kernel doesn't die. From that, I need to get the sum by per name and find the name with the highest count. Here is what could be useful:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("/Users/Desktop/EQR_Data/EQR_Transactions_1.csv", low_memory=False)
```

The column name I would like to import from my main file:

```
'seller_company_name'
```

Comment: Which column data do you want to sum if 'seller_company_name' is the only imported one?

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: All of the names in 'seller_company_data' are the ones I need to sum/count. There are 15 different names in the column, and each one has multiple entries. I need to sum those entries and find the name that came up the most.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you're better off just using the command line

if you have access to a unix like environment this is what grep / sed/ awk / cut were built for as they work with streams

See [here for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30906191/uniq-without-sorting-an-immense-text-file?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

An alternative would be to split your csv and batch it (delimited by ',' take 1st zero indexed column)

```
cat some.csv | cut -d, -f1 | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194349/how-do-i-split-a-file-into-n-no-of-parts for the file splitting

Answer (score -1):

For reading in just one column use the keyword `usecols`:

```
data = pd.read_csv("/Users/Desktop/EQR_Data/EQR_Transactions_1.csv", usecols=['seller_company_name'])
```

Then you can `groupby` seller names:

```
grpd = df.groupby('seller_company_name')
```

In grpd.groups is then a dict, which contains the list of occurence indices for each seller. Turn it into a dict with the lengths of these lists:

```
result = {d: len(grpd.groups[d]) for d in grpd.groups}
```