# How to get the list of dependent child images in Docker?

Tags: linux, docker, containers

I'm trying to remove an image and I get:

```
# docker rmi f50f9524513f  
Failed to remove image (f50f9524513f): Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete f50f9524513f (cannot be forced) - image has dependent child images
```

This is the docker version:

```
# docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.10.3
 API version:  1.22
 Go version:   go1.5.3
 Git commit:   20f81dd
 Built:        Thu Mar 10 21:49:11 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.10.3
 API version:  1.22
 Go version:   go1.5.3
 Git commit:   20f81dd
 Built:        Thu Mar 10 21:49:11 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

but there is no extra information:

```
# docker images --format="raw" | grep f50f9524513f -C3

repository: debian
tag: 8
image_id: f50f9524513f
created_at: 2016-03-01 18:51:14 +0000 UTC
virtual_size: 125.1 MB

repository: debian
tag: jessie
image_id: f50f9524513f
created_at: 2016-03-01 18:51:14 +0000 UTC
virtual_size: 125.1 MB
```

How can I get the **dependent child images** it claims to have?

there are no running nor stopped containers with that image id.

Comment: I have to wonder why docker team can't provide a native way to do this?

Comment: I fully agree with @Alkanshel, but to me this is not just an inconvenience, but also a security concern. Neither docker-cli now docker-hub provide more straight forward ways to find out what was baked into an image. Why is retrieving this such a pain???

Answer (score 73, accepted):

**Short answer:**
[Here is a python3 script](https://gist.github.com/altaurog/21ea7afe578a523e3dfe8d8a746f1e7d) that lists dependent docker images.

**Long answer:**
You can see the image id and parent id for all image created after the image in question with the following:

```
docker inspect --format='{{.Id}} {{.Parent}}' \
    $(docker images --filter since=f50f9524513f --quiet)
```

You should be able to look for images with parent id starting with f50f9524513f, then look for child images of *those*, etc..  *But* `.Parent` [isn’t what you think.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45821686/519015), so in most cases you would need to specify `docker images --all` above to make that work, then you will get image ids for all intermediate layers as well.

Here's a more limited python3 script to parse the docker output and do the searching to generate the list of images:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys

def desc(image_ids, links):
    if links:
        link, *tail = links
        if len(link) > 1:
            image_id, parent_id = link
            checkid = lambda i: parent_id.startswith(i)
            if any(map(checkid, image_ids)):
                return desc(image_ids | {image_id}, tail)
        return desc(image_ids, tail)
    return image_ids


def gen_links(lines):
    parseid = lambda s: s.replace('sha256:', '')
    for line in reversed(list(lines)):
        yield list(map(parseid, line.split()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    image_ids = {sys.argv[1]}
    links = gen_links(sys.stdin.readlines())
    trunc = lambda s: s[:12]
    print('\n'.join(map(trunc, desc(image_ids, links))))
```

If you save this as `desc.py` you could invoke it as follows:

```
docker images \
    | fgrep -f <(docker inspect --format='{{.Id}} {{.Parent}}' \
        $(docker images --all --quiet) \
        | python3 desc.py f50f9524513f )
```

Or just use [the gist above](https://gist.github.com/altaurog/21ea7afe578a523e3dfe8d8a746f1e7d), which does the same thing.

Comment: What if none of them start with the expect characters? Does that indicate a possible bug? I'm on Docker for Mac beta, FWIW, so that wouldn't surprise me.

Comment: Either it's a bug, or it means the image in question hasn't any children.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the original question. This shows what was created after the image in question, which may or may not be dependent upon the image the poster was trying to delete. Simon Brady's answer does the trick, for at least small sample sizes of images.

Comment: @penguincoder that's what the python script is for.

Comment: Like @neverfox, this answer didn't work for me.  Simon Brady's answer below did work, though.

Comment: @neverfox I figured out why it only worked in a limited set of cases.  I’ve updated my answer with an explanation, a fix, and a link to a complete script.

Comment: @Mark see above

Answer (score 141):

If you don't have a huge number of images, there's always the brute-force approach:

```
for i in $(docker images -q)
do
    docker history $i | grep -q f50f9524513f && echo $i
done | sort -u
```

Comment: I think this is the "best" solution.  You can expand this a little bit and make it a bit more clear what's what by changing the `echo $1` to the uglier (but still brute-forcy) `docker images | grep $i` (more portable in docker versions than using `--filter` flags for the Image Id)

Comment: You can add the `-q` flag to the `docker history` command to speed up execution a bit

Answer (score 20):

Install [dockviz](https://github.com/justone/dockviz/releases/latest) and follow the branches from the image id in the tree view:

```
dockviz images --tree -l
```

Comment: better to do `sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get install golang-go; export GOPATH=$HOME/.go` first.

Comment: Is available on macOS via `brew install dockviz`

Comment: Careful, when using Ubuntu. It's usually using outdated repositories for go

Comment: Shows a nice tree, but the image in question has no children in that tree, even though that is what docker says.

Answer (score 9):

I've created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/mlinhard/d460b2a6b3f6cd4426e554da040c0658) with shell script to print out descendant tree of a docker image, should anyone be interested in bash solution:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
parent_short_id=$1
parent_id=`docker inspect --format '{{.Id}}' $1`

get_kids() {
    local parent_id=$1
    docker inspect --format='ID {{.Id}} PAR {{.Parent}}' $(docker images -a -q) | grep "PAR ${parent_id}" | sed -E "s/ID ([^ ]*) PAR ([^ ]*)/\1/g"
}

print_kids() {
    local parent_id=$1
    local prefix=$2
    local tags=`docker inspect --format='{{.RepoTags}}' ${parent_id}`
    echo "${prefix}${parent_id} ${tags}"

    local children=`get_kids "${parent_id}"`

    for c in $children;
    do
        print_kids "$c" "$prefix  "
    done
}

print_kids "$parent_id" ""
```

Comment: I just had trouble formatting the code, so I gave up, thanks for doing this Jan

Comment: Hey @MichalLinhard! I found your snippet extremely useful. I have included it in https://github.com/PHPExpertsInc/DockerUpgrade/blob/master/docker-images-update If you could grant me (or everyone!) a MIT license to this code, it'd be highly appreciative!

Answer (score 5):

Based on [slushy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53037893/3364871) and [Michael Hoffman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11532197/3364871) answers, if you don't have a ton of images you can use this shell function:

```
docker_image_desc() {
  for image in $(docker images --quiet --filter "since=${1}"); do
    if [ $(docker history --quiet ${image} | grep ${1}) ]; then
      docker_image_desc "${image}"
    fi
  done
  echo "${1}"
}
```

and then call it using

```
docker_image_desc <image-id> | awk '!x[$0]++'
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a simple way to get a list of child images that are dependent on a parent image:

```sh
image_id=123456789012

docker images -a -q --filter since=$image_id |
xargs docker inspect --format='{{.Id}} {{.Parent}}' |
grep $image_id
```

That will generate a list of child/parent images IDs, for example (truncated for brevity):

```
sha256:abcdefghijkl sha256:123456789012
```

The left side is the child image ID, the right side is parent image ID that we are trying to delete, but it is saying "image has dependent child images". This tells us that `abcdefghijkl` is the child that is dependent on `123456789012`. So we need to first `docker rmi abcdefghijkl`, then you can `docker rmi 123456789012`.

Now, there may be a chain of dependent child images, so you may have to keep repeating to find the last child.

Comment: .. and the chain may be *much* longer than your time for this stepwise method:)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution based on the Python API (`pip install docker`) that recursively lists descendants together with their tags (if any), increasing the indentation according to the depth of the relationship (children, grandchildren, etc.):

```py
import argparse
import docker

def find_img(img_idx, id):
    try:
        return img_idx[id]
    except KeyError:
        for k, v in img_idx.items():
            if k.rsplit(":", 1)[-1].startswith(id):
                return v
    raise RuntimeError("No image with ID: %s" % id)

def get_children(img_idx):
    rval = {}
    for img in img_idx.values():
        p_id = img.attrs["Parent"]
        rval.setdefault(p_id, set()).add(img.id)
    return rval

def print_descendants(img_idx, children_map, img_id, indent=0):
    children_ids = children_map.get(img_id, [])
    for id in children_ids:
        child = img_idx[id]
        print(" " * indent, id, child.tags)
        print_descendants(img_idx, children_map, id, indent=indent+2)

def main(args):
    client = docker.from_env()
    img_idx = {_.id: _ for _ in client.images.list(all=True)}
    img = find_img(img_idx, args.id)
    children_map = get_children(img_idx)
    print_descendants(img_idx, children_map, img.id)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=__doc__)
    parser.add_argument("id", metavar="IMAGE_ID")
    main(parser.parse_args())
```

Example:

```
$ python find_dep_img.py 549afbf12931
 sha256:913d0981fdc7d2d673f2c8135b7afd32ba5037755e89b00432d3460422ba99b9 []
   sha256:0748dbc043b96ef9f88265c422e0267807f542e364b7a7fadf371ba5ee082b5d []
     sha256:6669414d2a0cc31b241a1fbb00c0ca00fa4dc4fa65dffb532bac90d3943d6a0a []
       sha256:a6441e7d9e92511608aad631f9abe8627033de41305c2edf7e03ee36f94f0817 ['foo/bar:latest']
```

I've made it available as a gist at https://gist.github.com/simleo/10ad923f9d8a2fa410f7ec2d7e96ad57

Answer (score 3):

This is what I did in order to preserve my final "image" (layer, really - which is what threw me off, as I am just getting into docker builds).

I was getting the whole "... cannot be forced..." message. I realized I couldn't delete the images I didn't need because they are not really independent images created by 'docker commit'. My issue was, I had several images (or layers) between the base image and my final, and just trying to clean up is where I met the error/warning about the child and parent.

1. I exported the final image (or layer, if you will) out to a tarball.
2. I then deleted all the images I wanted to, including my final - I have it saved to a tarball so, while I wasn't sure if I would be able to use it, I was just experimenting.
3. I then ran `docker image load -i FinalImage.tar.gz`. The output was something like:

---

```
7d9b54235881: Loading layer [==================================================>]  167.1MB/167.1MB
c044b7095786: Loading layer [==================================================>]  20.89MB/20.89MB
fe94dbd0255e: Loading layer [==================================================>]  42.05MB/42.05MB
19abaa1dc0d4: Loading layer [==================================================>]  37.96MB/37.96MB
4865d7b6fdb2: Loading layer [==================================================>]  169.6MB/169.6MB
a0c115c7b87c: Loading layer [==================================================>]    132MB/132MB
```

Loaded image ID: sha256:82d4f8ef9ea1eab72d989455728762ed3c0fe35fd85acf9edc47b41dacfd6382

Now, when I list with 'docker image ls', I only have the original base image, and the final image I previously saved to a tarball.

```
[root@docker1 ~]# docker image ls
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
httpd               import              82d4f8ef9ea1        3 days ago          747MB
centos              httpd               36540f359ca3        5 weeks ago         193MB
```

---

My system is 'clean' now. I only have the images I want. 
I even deleted the base image without a problem.

```
[root@docker1 ~]# docker rmi 36540f359ca3
Untagged: centos:httpd
Untagged:     centos@sha256:c1010e2fe2b635822d99a096b1f4184becf5d1c98707cbccae00be663a9b9131
Deleted: sha256:36540f359ca3b021d4b6a37815e9177b6c2bb3817598979ea55aee7ecc5c2c1f
```

Comment: Good answer, but load is only supposed to be used on an image created from "docker save". The proper restore for a "docker export" is "docker import"

Answer (score 0):

You can delete Docker images irrespective of parent and child relation through the below directory of Docker

```
/var/lib/docker/image/devicemapper/imagedb/content/sha256
```

In this directory you can find Docker images, so you can delete what you want.

Comment: I'm trying to make portable commands using the docker API, assuming device mapper and docker engine (as opposed to docker swarm for example) makes this a non portable solution. Also is risky to be deleting files in the filesystem while other process (including the docker daemon) could be using it.

Comment: where is it on macos?

Comment: *WARNING" this can cause multiple errors with deleting and pulling containers in future. Never delete dirs in `/var/lib/docker` directly by hand

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
ID=$(docker inspect --format="{{.Id}}" "$1")
IMAGES=$(docker inspect --format="{{if eq \"$ID\" .Config.Image}}{{.Id}}{{end}}" $(docker images --filter since="$ID" -q))
echo $(printf "%s\n" "${IMAGES[@]}" | sort -u)
```

It'll print the child image id's, with the `sha256:` prefix.
I also had the following, which appends the names:

```
IMAGES=$(docker inspect --format="{{if eq \"$ID\" .Config.Image}}{{.Id}}{{.RepoTags}}{{end}}" $(docker images --filter since="$ID" -q))
```

---

- `ID=` Gets the full id of the image
- `IMAGES=` Gets all child images that have this image listed as an `Image`
- `echo...` Removes duplicates and echos the results

Comment: I like the Go format conditionals, but maybe they are better as a filter for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

I cooked up this to recursively find children, their repo tags, and print what they're doing:

```
docker_img_tree() {
    for i in $(docker image ls -qa) ; do
        [ -f "/tmp/dii-$i"  ] || ( docker image inspect $i > /tmp/dii-$i)
        if grep -qiE 'Parent.*'$1 /tmp/dii-$i ; then
            echo "$2============= $i (par=$1)"
            awk '/(Cmd|Repo).*\[/,/\]/' /tmp/dii-$i | sed "s/^/$2/"
            docker_img_tree $i $2===
        fi
    done
}
```

Don't forget to delete /tmp/dii-* if your host isn't secure.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script that directly gives the dependent child images ids, using awk:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
set -e
parent=$1
echo "Dependent Child Images IDs of $parent "
docker inspect --format='{{.Id}} {{.Parent}}' \
$(docker images --all --quiet --filter since=$parent) \
| awk -v parent=$parent '{ if($2 == parent) print $1 }'
```

It's used by passing the parent image id as first parameter:

```bash
$ ./get_children_of.sh sha256:15f16e6da280b21e8d3b17ac49022732a553550a15ad2d0d12d5cf22b36254cb
Dependent Child IDs of sha256:15f16e6da280b21e8d3b17ac49022732a553550a15ad2d0d12d5cf22b36254cb 
sha256:c18db0311efb263c0f52e520d107b02a373aac7a4821164e7a1b46b14a3a1419
```

Answer (score -7):

I was also facing the same issue. Fallowed steps below to resolve the issue.

**Stop all running containers**

docker stop $(docker ps -aq)
**Remove all containers**

docker rm $(docker ps -aq)
**Remove all images**

docker rmi $(docker images -q)

Comment: this answer not meets questioner requirement.

Comment: Please stop commenting things that people could potentially copy&paste and do harmful things.