# Ubuntu Docker - php composer build from the official Dockerfile fails, COPY failed Step 9/12 stat no such file or directory

Tags: docker, build, composer-php, dockerfile

I want to build a docker image of a composer from this page [composer:latest](https://hub.docker.com/_/composer/) and taking exactly this [Dockerfile](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/composer/docker/edf4f0abf50da5d967408849434b9053a195b65f/1.7/Dockerfile)

but when I do this in console:

```
$ wget -O Dockerfile https://raw.githubusercontent.com/composer/docker/edf4f0abf50da5d967408849434b9053a195b65f/1.7/Dockerfile
$ docker build -t mycomposer:latest .
```

i got this build error:

> Step 9/12 : COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh COPY
>   failed: stat
>   /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder787686173/docker-entrypoint.sh: no
>   such file or directory

How come I have any error building from official Dockerfile? 
This way works:

```
$ docker pull composer:latest
```

but I need to build an image basing on a local Dockerfile instead of just pulling it.

Comment: Do you have the whole https://github.com/composer/docker/ repository, or just the one Dockerfile?  Why can't you use the prebuilt image?

Comment: no, I just downloaded Dockerfile itself and used it to do build (two lines of console commands). I wanted to use prebuild Dockerfile as a template to make my own version but I'm not even able to build it unmodified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command

```
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh
```

in the Dockerfile tries to copy the file *docker-entrypoint.sh* from your current directory.
However you have only downloaded the Dockerfile.

If you visit the actual [directory](https://github.com/composer/docker/tree/master/1.7) on the [repository](https://github.com/composer/docker) you will notice another file entitled
*docker-entrypoint.sh*. If you download this file too and place it in the same directory
as the Dockerfile the image will be built without errors.

Comment: downloading docker-entrypoint.sh to the dir of Dockerfile helped, the build is done but besides the image I wanted I have also created 10 others named none:none with the same size, do you know why they ware created/not removed?

Comment: In the process of building an image, Docker creates these intermediate images to help with caching for repeated builds. `docker image prune` will remove dangling images, such as the <none>:<none> type you mentioned.

Comment: `docker image prune` did not work, all intermediate images left and when i wanted to remove some of them with `docker rmi #image-id` I got err: unable to delete #image-id (cannot be forced) - image has dependent child images

Comment: I believe those images are the remains of previous unsuccessful builds. I think this is what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43463968/6504247