# Eliminate docker <none> images when building using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am working on a microservice with several docker containers. Using docker-compose creates the images I want but also several other copies of  images which fill up my disk space. What are the use of this other child images and can I stop them from being created since they are using up my memory. Please note they are not really "dangling" they just appear on build.

[image: composetest_web image has 5 child images below it.]

Comment: Question about your error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38118791/can-t-delete-docker-image-with-dependent-child-images

Comment: How are you seeing these images?  Why do you think they're causing problems?  Can you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 2):

The  images are the intermediate layers resulted from docker build. They are the parent layers for your final image and cannot be removed as your `latest` image actually refers to them.

Only those images which are not referenced by any other layers can be removed. These images are called `dangling`. You can use the following command to remove the dangling images:

`docker rmi $(docker images -f "dangling=true" -q)`

Comment: Well trying to delete either of the dangling images gives the error [Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete c565603bc87f (cannot be forced) - image has dependent child images]

Comment: What do you mean by "either of the dangling images"? What is the output of `docker images -f "dangling=true" -q`?

Comment: It gives a list of image ids, when I list the images again they are still on the list and when I try to delete them, I get the error above

Comment: What is your docker version? It should have worked. You can also try [`docker image prune`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/).

Comment: My docker version is 18.09 and the prune command does not really get any dangling images... I am wondering, aren't all those untagged images dangling? why are they not being deleted then?

Comment: Like I said in my answer, all untagged images are not dangling. Please read this article - https://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2015/07/what-are-docker-none-none-images/

Comment: I appreciate the blog.. but mind you my images are several express servers and two react frontends. I have the node images pulled and used in building my custom images.. After checking on parent dependency, about four <none> images are dependent on either of my created image.. why are they so many?