# Image building issue docker meteor

Tags: docker, meteor, dockerfile, docker-image, docker-build

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80obb.png)
I have an issue with docker,  i want to dockerize my meteor project, but when i build image using my dockerfile,  it create several images tagged as  and i can't delete theme, it take lot of space.
I have this error when i try to delete thes images.
"Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 080b558d2885 (cannot be forced) - image has dependent child images"

PS :

i followed this tutorial : https://dockerize.io/guides/docker-meteor-guide

project is available at : https://github.com/khakan95/meteor2

Comment: you could stop your entire running container and delete it if that helps

Comment: i tried it's not working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can’t delete docker image with dependent child images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38118791/can-t-delete-docker-image-with-dependent-child-images)