# How to know which base image is used to build a image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a image and I want to know what is the base image used to build it. In other words what was the

```
FROM base_image?
```

I have tried docker inspect which was very informative but it doesn't answer what  we are looking for.

Comment: `docker history $image-id` command might help. But it ddidn't seems to print the base image. There is another such similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45821389/is-docker-inspect-f-parent-a-safe-way-to-get-the-base-image-id

Comment: docker history doesn't help, docker inspect $image_id was much informative though.

Comment: Found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19104847/how-to-generate-a-dockerfile-from-an-image but it don't correctly shows the base image