# How to identify a Scratch Image using Docker Inspect?

Tags: docker

Is there any field in the docker inspect that can identify a docker scratch image ( image without an OS) https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/baseimages/?

If not is there any other way to detect an image without an OS ?

What does the RepoDigests  field  in the `docker inspect`represent ?

Comment: What do you mean by a "docker scratch image"? Do you mean an image with no content?

Comment: I would think that all images are somehow based on scratch if you go back far enough. For example ubuntu here: https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/blob/1c090689a541a57452ae21cb76ef038b9f339fb2/focal/Dockerfile

Comment: Not really, however if you have built the image yourself you could use `docker history`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45821686/10093070

Comment: What even is "an image without an OS"? An image can be as small as a single binary and still be functional. Can you tell us more about exactly what you're trying to do?