# Regex to delete lines that match the first string?

Tags: regex, replace, duplicates

I have long list of lines with a lot of situations line this,
lines that have identical first word (first string before space), but the rest is different.
I need to keep only one line with unique first string.

```
john jane
john 123
john jim jane
jane john
jane 123
jane 456
jim
jim 1
```

To have this result:

```
john jane
jane john
jim
```

So, if first word in line is the match, delete all but one line.

I can delete all duplicate lines, but leave with lines like in example above,

```
^(.*)(\r?\n\1)+$
```

This regex delete identical lines, not like in the example.
If there is regex or notepad macro to solve this?

Comment: Not the best solution for Notepad++: `^((\w+\b).*)\r?\n\2.*` -> `$1` and hit *Replace All* multiple times.

Comment: Are the lines with the same first "word" always consecutive? And please answer to anubhava question if you want relevant answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Notepad++ *(assuming lines with the same first word are consecutive)*:

search: `^(\S++).*\K(?:\R\1(?:\h.*|$))+`
replacement: nothing

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/qC8cD0/1)

pattern details:

```
^             # start of the line
(\S++)        # the first "word" (all that isn't a whitespace) captured in group 1
.*            # all characters until the end of the line
\K            # remove characters matched before from the match result
(?:
    \R        # a newline
    \1        # reference to the capture group 1 (same first word)
    (?:
        \h.*  # a horizontal whitespace 
      |       # OR
        $     # the end of the line
    )
)+            # repeat one or more times
```

Comment: Confirmed, it is working for my file. Works in ultraedit as well, use it because Notepad++ cant handle very large files.

Comment: @Jim8645: note that if you use unix/linux, sp asic awk approach is interesting for large files since it doesn't need to load all the file in memory.

Answer (score 2):

if you have `awk`

```
awk '!seen[$1]++' infile.txt
```

adapted from this thread: [Unix: removing duplicate lines without sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532157/unix-removing-duplicate-lines-without-sorting/11532197#11532197)

Answer (score 0):

In Perl:

```
s/^((\w+).*)\n(?:(?:\2.*\n)*)/$1/gm
```

You can give it a try with this:

```
#!/bin/usr/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $file = "john jane
john 123
john jim jane
jane john
jane 123
jane 456
jim
jim 1
";

$file =~ s/^((\w+).*)\n(?:(?:\2.*\n)*)/$1\n/gm;

print $file;
```