# How to remove repeated lines but not sorting (keep the initial order)

Tags: linux, sorting, terminal, text-processing, data-processing

I have this input:

```
Host: ping.chartbeat.net
Host: extra.test.co
userblablabla
Host: extra.test.co
Host: extra.test.co
Host: extra.test.co
Host: extra.test.co
Host: extra.test.co
Host: extra.test.co
Host: extra.test.co
Host: extra.test.co
Host: secure.test.com
userlalalalala
Host: ping.chartbeat.net
Host: secure.test.com
Host: secure.test.com
Host: secure.test.com
```

and I want to convert it into this:

```
Host: ping.chartbeat.net
Host: extra.test.co
userblablabla
Host: secure.test.com
userlalalalala
```

How do I perform that¿?

I tried `|sort -u` but that breaks the order in which I want the lines

Comment: Why is `Host: extra.test.co` repeated twice in the final output? and `Host: secure.test.com` is missing?

Comment: @Inian presumably they only want to remove lines when they are repeating the line directly above, not any further line already seen, but yes, the logic should be explained clearly rather than requiring people to infer/guess it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unix: removing duplicate lines without sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532157/unix-removing-duplicate-lines-without-sorting)

Comment: But then the second `Host: ping.chartbeat.net` and `Host: secure.test.com` would be missing. OP, please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `uniq <file>`. [uniq is part of the GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/uniq-invocation.html).