# Is it possible to see which branches I used in git?

Tags: git, branch, history, git-checkout

Is it possible to see which branches I used in git?

I would like to see something like the branches checkout history in git. Is it possible to do somehow or does this kind of information not stored by git?

I was not able to find an answer to my question by googling.

E.g. if I run the commands: `git checkout -b feature/foo`, `git checkout -b feature/bar`, then the last two records in the history I am looking for I am expecting to see something similar to the:

```
...
feature/foo
feature/bar
```

Comment: `git reflog` could help. But it does not print in the format as you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to [ElpieKay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6330106/elpiekay)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66312039/is-it-possible-to-see-which-branches-i-used-in-git#comment117233955_66312039), [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jordan-brough/48e2803c0ffa6dc2e0bd) from [Jordan Brough](https://github.com/jordan-brough) can help listing the past branches you have used.

It is based on [`reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog):

```sh
BRANCHES=(
  $(git reflog |
    egrep -io "moving from ([^[:space:]]+)" |
    awk '{ print $3 }' | # extract 3rd column
    awk ' !x[$0]++' | # Removes duplicates.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532157
    egrep -v '^[a-f0-9]{40}$' | # remove hash results
    while read line; do # verify existence
      ([[ $CHECK_EXISTENCE = '0' ]] || git rev-parse --verify "$line" &>/dev/null) && echo "$line"
    done |
    head -n "$NUM"
  )
)
```

But keep in mind that reflog is limited in time (90 days by default)