# Running an awk command with $SHELL -c returns different results

Tags: awk, zsh

I am trying to [use `awk` to print the unique lines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11532197) returned by a command. For simplicity, assume the command is `ls -alh`.

If I run the following command in my Z shell, `awk` shows all lines printed by `ls -alh`

```
ls -alh | awk '!seen[$0]++'
```

However, if I run the same command with `$SHELL -c` while escaping the ! with backslash, I only see the first line of the output printed.

```
$SHELL -c "ls -alh | awk '\!seen[$0]++'"
```

How can I ensure the latter command prints the exact same outputs as the former?

EDIT 1:

I initially thought the ! could be the issue. But changing the expression `'!seen[$0]++'` to `'seen[$0]++==0'` has the same problem.

EDIT 2:

It looks like I should have escaped $ too. Since I do not know the reason behind it, I will not post an answer.

Comment: what is the output from `echo "${SHELL}"` ?

Comment: This is crazy anyway. `$SHELL` could be e.g. `/bin/csh` or `/bin/fish` whose syntax is completely different from Bourne shell. Simply run `sh` if that's what you mean.

Comment: My `$SHELL` is zsh. I am just curious why this command has to be run differently when invoked with `$SHELL` and without, even if both are zsh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second form, `$0` is being treated as a shell variable in the double-quoted string.  The substitution creates an interestingly mangled `awk` command:

```bash
> print $SHELL -c "ls -alh | awk '\!seen[$0]++'"
/bin/zsh -c ls -alh | awk '!seen[-zsh]++'
```

The variable is not substituted in the first form since it is inside single quotes.

This answer discusses how single- and double-quoted strings are treated in `bash` and `zsh`:
[Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

---

Escaping the `$` so that `$0` is passed to `awk` should work, but note that quoting in commands that are parsed multiple times can get really tricky.

```bash
> print $SHELL -c "ls -alh | awk '\!seen[\$0]++'"
/bin/zsh -c ls -alh | awk '!seen[$0]++'
```