# How do I find calls to a function in Git from another file?

Tags: c#, git

I have a project in Git.  In my code, at some point in the past, I removed a call to a public function.  I would like to know when I removed the call to this function, and why.  Because the function call is in a different file than the function definition, I can't simply look at the file history of the file that defines the function.  Is there an easy way to look for files that contain calls to a function?

I'll try to illustrate this:

```
File: MyFuncCall.cs //older version

    public void Foo()
    {
        //do something ...
    }

File: ???.cs //older version

    public void Bar()
    {
        new MyFuncCall().Foo();
        //do something else...
    }
```

After some commits, the code now looks like:

```
File: MyFuncCall.cs //newer version

    public void Foo()
    {
        //do something ...
    }

File: ???.cs //newer version

    public void Bar()
    {
        //no more call to function
        //do something else...
    }
```

In this illustration, I want to know what ???.cs is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called the log "[pickaxe](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitdiffcore.html#_diffcore-pickaxe:_for_detecting_addition/deletion_of_specified_string)" ([`git log`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log)):

```
git log -Sfunction
```

The oldest one will be the commit where that function has been introduced in your code.
The next one can be where it has been deleted.

See "[How to grep git commits for a certain word](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1340245/6309)": it differs from `git log --grep=function`, which greps within the commit message.

Comment: Cool.  It'd be nice if that git command showed not only the commit information, but also the file name containing the search phrase.  All I needed to do was a quick text search of the commit.  Thanks.

Comment: @user2023861 then `git log -p` can help too (http://stackoverflow.com/a/23128003/6309). Otherwise, regarding `git log -S`, maybe adding `-U0` can help too (http://stackoverflow.com/a/14164826/6309)